# discord.py Blacklist words or certain commands

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to blacklist words or certain commands in a specific channel. In the channel #verify, I only want commands that start with e?verify to be processed. If the command does not start with e?verify or is just a word (not a command), I want the bot to delete the message and not process the command.

I have tried

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.id == 775951693820985404:
        if not message.content.lower().startswith('e?verify'):
            await message.delete()
        else:
            await bot.process_commands(message)
```

But it does not work. Can anyone help?

Edit: Also, my bot does not respond to commands in any other channels.

Comment: How is your code not working. Does it not delete the message? Does it delete every message? Does it not process certain messages? Does it spit out an error?

Comment: If it is the blacklisted words/commands, it deletes them (which is good). However, if I do e?verify, it still deletes the message and does not process the command.

Comment: try to print out `message.content` and `message.content.lower().startswith('e?verify')` to narrow down the problem. From your description it seems like the `startswith` method always returns `True`, even when it shouldnt

Comment: When I type something that is not e?verify, it returns False. However, when I type e?verify, it returns True

Comment: What does `e?verify` should do ?

Comment: It just sends a message which the user needs to react to.